Error when installing evaluate library in miniconda3
I've just installed a fresh miniconda3 on my computer (ubuntu 22.04) by following the instructions from the official doc.
My goal is to work with the hugging face's ecosystem with some langage models. But I get an error when installing the evaluate library.
In my shell I do conda install evaluate and I get the following error:
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package evaluate-0.3.0-py310h06a4308_0 requires python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ evaluate is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ evaluate [0.3.0|0.4.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ evaluate 0.3.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ evaluate [0.3.0|0.4.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ evaluate [0.3.0|0.4.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ evaluate 0.4.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Any idea of what to do?

The error clearly says
package evaluate-0.3.0-py310h06a4308_0 requires 
python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Create a venv and take your project from there in anaconda Prompt - Reference
conda create -n huggingface-env python=3.10

Then
conda activate huggingface-env

Then
pip install evaluate

Followed by rest of your libs
Make sure from the next time you want to run the project again you have to activate the environment and work from there

There is no anaconda::evaluate  version that supports Python 3.12+ which I think you are using.

Use an older python version <3.12

Use conda install conda-forge::evaluate which is 0.4.1 and not 0.4.0 from the current anaconda channel.
Note that the latest release is 0.4.3, which should work for Python 3.8+.

If you do not mind not using conda use pip to install 0.4.3 with
pip install evaluate.


